# Can a temporal table historize insert?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2019, temporal-tables

I have created the following temportal table

```
/*
ALTER TABLE [dbo].________Test SET ( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.________Test
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.________TestHistory
GO
*/

CREATE TABLE dbo.________Test
(
    DeptID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , DeptName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  , ManagerID INT NULL
  , ParentDeptID INT NULL
  , SysStartTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL
  , SysEndTime DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL
  , PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime)
-- ) WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON); 
) WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.________TestHistory));
```

Now I can insert, update and delete values. 
But the values do only get historized on an update or a delete. 
**Is there a way to historize the insert-statements, too ?**

I want to avoid having to write a trigger for that, if at all possible... 
Having the data in two tables is extremely disadvantageous, because then i need to create a union first, and miss out on any field created afterwards, or I have potentially garbage columns if I use SELECT * and create a union-view, if the column-order gets altered, plus new columns would be missing, too.

Hmmm, those temporal tables seem to be really stupid(ly made)... 
Apparently, they historize every potential change, even if there's no change in the data. 
So I can do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_________Test_AfterInsert ON dbo.________Test
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE dbo.________Test 
        SET DeptID = DeptID 
    WHERE DeptID IN 
    (
        SELECT DeptID
        FROM inserted
    )
END
```

And the entries will swiftly be historized after insert. 
On the other hand, this is nice, since then I don't have to manually synchronize the table-schema with the history-table-schema.

Comment: `select ...from table FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL` is meant to query all data like a union view would do but without the drawbacks you describe

Comment: @nfgl: Thanks, that solves the mystery.